# video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

When I run the following code I get an error. Most of the other similar posts talks about   pygame.quit()
sys.exit() which I have, but still see the error

```
import pygame, sys, math
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
ball = pygame.image.load("GolfBall.png").convert_alpha()
ball_rect= ball.get_rect()
is_playing= True
while is_playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_playing= False
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(20)
    pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.............................", line 10, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: You are calling `pygame.quit()` every iteration of the main loop.  Probably it's that.

Comment: Do `pygame.quit()` after the application loop, not in the application loop.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.quit()` should be out of the loop:

```
import pygame, sys, math
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
ball = pygame.image.load("GolfBall.png").convert_alpha()
ball_rect= ball.get_rect()
is_playing= True
while is_playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_playing= False
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(20)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Otherwise after the first iteration of the loop, `pygame.quit()` would have been called and on the second iteration the error would have occured.

Answer (score 0):

You have to care about the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

While `pygame.quit()` has to be done after the main application loop (as mentioned in another answer and the comments), drawing the scene and the update of the display has to be done in the main application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
import pygame, sys, math
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
ball = pygame.image.load("GolfBall.png").convert_alpha()
ball_rect= ball.get_rect()

# application loop
is_playing= True
while is_playing:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_playing= False

    #<--| INDENTATION

    # draw the scene
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.time.wait(20) 

#<--| INDENTATION

# quit pygame   
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Note, the event loop is executed once for each event, but the application loop is executed   once for each frame.